# Python - decoded unicode string does not stay decoded

Tags: python, unicode

It may be too late at night for me to be still doing programming (so apologies if this is a very silly thing to ask), but I have spotted a weird behaviour with string decoding in Python:

```
>>> bs = bytearray(b'I\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00l\x00(\x00R\x00)\x00')
>>> name = bs.decode("utf-8", "replace")
>>> print(name)
I n t e l ( R )
>>> list_of_dict = []
>>> list_of_dict.append({'name': name})
>>> list_of_dict
[{'name': 'I\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00l\x00(\x00R\x00)\x00'}]
```

How can the list contain unicode characters if it has already been decoded?

Comment: a) You created bytearray `bs`, b) decoded from `bs` unicode value `name`,  c) created dict with this unicode value `{"name": name}`, d) appended this dict into empty list e)you got a list with dict that contains unicode value. So? What is weird in your opinion?

Comment: `print` uses `str` while repl by default uses `repr`. If you directly type `name` or 
`print(repr(name))` instead of `print(name)`. Well, you know what you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding bytes by definition produces "Unicode" (text really, where Unicode is how you can store arbitrary text, so Python uses it internally for all text), so when you say "How can the list contain unicode characters if it has already been decoded?" it betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of what Unicode is. If you have a `str` in Python 3, it's text, and that text is composed of a series of Unicode code points (with unspecified internal encoding; in fact, modern Python stores in ASCII, latin-1, UCS-2 or UCS-4, depending on highest ordinal value, as well as sometimes caching a UTF-8 representation, or a native `wchar` representation for use with legacy extension modules).

You're seeing the `repr` of the nul character (Unicode ordinal 0) and thinking it didn't decode properly, and you're likely right (there's nothing illegal about nul characters, they're just not common in plain text); your input data is almost certainly encoded in UTF-16-LE, not UTF-8. Use the correct codec, and the text comes out correctly:

```
>>> bs = bytearray(b'I\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00l\x00(\x00R\x00)\x00')
>>> bs.decode('utf-16-le')  # No need to replace things, this is legit UTF-16-LE
'Intel(R)'
>>> list_of_dict = [{'name': _}]
>>> list_of_dict
[{'name': 'Intel(R)'}]
```

Point is, while producing nul characters is legal, unless it's a binary file, odds are it won't have any, and if you're getting them, you probably picked the wrong codec.

The discrepancy between printing the `str` and displaying is as part of a `list`/`dict` is because `list`/`dict` stringify with the `repr` of their contents (what you'd type to reproduce the object programmatically in many cases), so the string is rendered with the `\x00` escapes. `print`ing the `str` directly doesn't involve the `repr`, so the nul characters get rendered as spaces (since there is no printable character for nul, so your terminal chose to render it as spaces).

Answer (score 1):

So what I think is happening is that the null terminated characters `\x00` are not properly decoded and remain in the string after decoding. However, since these are null characters they do not mess up when you print the string which interprets them as nothing or spaces (in my case I tested your code on arch linux on python2 and python3 and they were completely ommited)

Now the thing is that you got a `\x00` character for each of your string characters when you decode with utf-8 so what this means is that your bytestream consists actually out of 16bit characters and not 8bit. Therefore, if you try to decode using `utf-16` your code will work like a charm :)

```
>>> bs = bytearray(b'I\x00n\x00t\x00e\x00l\x00(\x00R\x00)\x00')
>>> t = bs.decode("utf-16", "replace")
>>> print(t)
Intel(R)
>>> t
'Intel(R)'
```

Comment: Given the lack of a BOM and the obviously little endian text, you'd want to explicitly specify `utf-16-le`, or else your code will work fine until the day you run it on a big-endian system and `utf-16` implicitly means `utf-16-be`, making your output the rather inscrutable `'䤀渀琀攀氀⠀刀⤀'` (I'm hoping I didn't just say something offensive to deaf Chinese folks in that mix of Chinese and Braille it produced).

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know about specific modes for little or big endian for decoding. I think for the majority of PC applications LE is probably the thumb rule, but yeah it is always better to have control over anything :)

Comment: Thank you, @GregK. this is a valuable answer!